# Reading a paragraph from the command line on java console program

Tags: java, console, readline, eof, paragraph

The while loop in the following program does not terminate so I can't get the output in the last line that tries to print the variable paragraph to console. There are similar problems but the solutions are not practicle and I could not do them. Please suggest a solution.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Test {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String line = "";
        String paragraph = "";

        System.out.println("Enter the text: ");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(isr);
             while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
             {
                  paragraph = paragraph + line + " ";
             }
          isr.close();
          bufferedReader.close();
          System.out.println(paragraph);
    }//method main ends here

}
```

Comment: it wont terminate because Input value should not take any NULL values

Comment: let say you dont give any input , that doesn't mean the line is assigned null , its not null , you cant input null from command line , so the condition is never get true !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code

`while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)`

will never be true if you dont assign null to line , and you cant assign null to an object through console , so that means you have to code it for something , like enter key or any other character to end the input.

like

```
while(!(line.equals("exit")))
{
      //whatever
}
```

This means when you type exit at end , the program will terminate and print the paragraph.

You can try this snippet

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

    public class Test {


        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            String line = "";
            String paragraph = "";

            System.out.println("Enter the text: ");
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(isr);
                 do
                 {
                     line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                      paragraph = paragraph + line + " ";
                 }while(!line.equals("exit"));
              isr.close();
              bufferedReader.close();
              System.out.println(paragraph);
        }//method main ends here

    }
```

Comment: anshulkatta Thank you very much for the suggested solution. It works!

Answer (score 0):

Please replace this 'while(!line.isBlank());' in the above snippet of code

```
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    try {

        do
        {
            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            paragraph = paragraph + line + " \n ";

        }while(!line.isBlank());

        bufferedReader.close();
        System.out.println(paragraph);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

You need to hit enter twice after you paste required content in console to see the output